# ls utility cannot interpret ambiguous file references?

Tags: command-line, ls

In one of my favourite Linux textbooks, I found a statement that `ls`  utility cannot interpret ambiguous file references. The argument, more or less, goes like this: "First `ls` is called with an argument of `?old`. The shell expands `?old` into a matching filename, `hold`, and passes that name to `ls`. The second command is the same as the first, except the `?`  is  protected with `'\'`. The shell does not recognize this question mark as a special character and passes it to `ls`. `ls` also cannot interpret it:

```
$ ls ?old
hold
ls \?old
ls: ?old: No such file or  directory
```

My question: here it is Shell which cannot interpret because of the backslash. So, this example shows only that with backslash neither shell nor `ls` can interpret ambiguous file reference. It does not prove that without backslash `ls` cannot interpret ambiguous file references. What I got wrong here?

Comment: The `\?` could not be expanded in shell and `ls` could not find any flie with name `?old`. Everything is perfect. What is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Without the backslash: the shell interprets `?`, expands `?old` to `hold`, and so the argument that `ls` receives is `hold`.
- With the backslash: the shell does not interpret `?`, but it does interpret `\?` to mean a literal `?`, and passes it as `?` to `ls`. So the argument that `ls` receives is `?old`. **`ls` does not see the backslash.**

Comment: Another way to look at that is that whatever  you type into the shell, first is interpreted by the shell, and only then gets passed to the actual command you want. This is the source of a lot of confusion especially when quotes or special characters are involved, but so long as you remember that shell parses everything first, and then the command - you'll do just fine.